# printing a variable in a makefile with multiple spaces

Tags: makefile

Consider the following simple makefile:

```
define HELP_MSG
  
Usage:\n
        make help -show this message\n
        make help                   -show spaces and then this message\n

endef
export HELP_MSG

help:
        @echo $$HELP_MSG
```

which outputs:

```
Usage:
 make help -show this message
 make help -show spaces and then this message
```

How can I have `@echo` respect the extra spacing on the second output line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no portable way to print formatted text with `echo`.  The `-e` option to `echo` is not standardized and not all versions of `echo` support `-e`.  You should never try to print anything other than simple text that you know does not begin with a dash (`-`).  Basically, anything other than a simple static string.

For anything more complex, you should use `printf`.

Also, if you want to print non-trivial text you *MUST* quote it, otherwise the shell will interpret it and mess it up for you.

```
help:
        @printf '%s\n' "$$HELP_MSG"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use -e along with echo and use tab for space. Eg:

```
define HELP_MSG
  
Usage:\n
        make help -show this message\n
        make help \t-show spaces and then this message\n

endef
export HELP_MSG

help:
        @echo -e $$HELP_MSG
```

To add custom spaces, use printf or " " in echo. Eg:

```
define HELP_MSG
  
Usage:\n
        make help -show this message\n
        make help           -show spaces and then this message\n

endef
export HELP_MSG

help:
    @echo -e "$$HELP_MSG"
    @printf '%s\n' "$$HELP_MSG"
```

Comment: OK.  This enabled me to print tabs.  What if I wanted to print some arbitrary number of spaces?

Comment: @rhz I have edited the answer for an arbitrary number of spaces.